# What other hacks exist to disconnect a "quick-connect"-style fuel line?

Tags: tools, diy, fuel-line

I'm in the process of preparing my Lumina's engine and transmission for extraction ([progress here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51715/zaids-lumina-diary)).

This 3/8" GM fuel rail is supplied by a flex hose with a "quick-connect" connector. <sub>If only it disconnected as quickly...</sub>

[image: Fuel Rail Connector]

I ended up using a dedicated (rather pricey) disconnect tool:

[image: Fuel Disconnect Tool]

**Question**

Must one purchase a dedicated disconnect tool for this job? I'm already aware of the [sacrificial Sharpie lid](https://youtu.be/hkZRSMGqQ0E) approach, which strikes me as a bit of a hit-and-miss affair in the video.

What other ingenious solutions do people use for this kind of job? Are there any risks associated with them?

Comment: I much prefer this approach. I've always gone with the "destroy n' replace" method. Pricier and more time consuming, but definitely easier the next time! "Quick disconnect" is right up there with "plug n' play" on computers of the 90s.

Answer (score 1):

Use the proper disconnect tool. You do not want to damage the line and have to replace it, or have it leak.

Depending on where you buy it, sometimes the tools can be expensive especially in smaller parts stores. Amazon sells several fuel line disconnect tool kits for under $10.